# using datatables with JSP does not return the query data in the table and sends me an error

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json

malfunction in ajax request in datatables returns me an error with the following message

DataTables warning: table id=tablaEstudiantes - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

[revising on the console does not return me any value as below screenshot shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm5O9.png)

[as you can see in the ajax does not return any data attached the code in javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx3o2.png)

as you can see in the ajax does not return any data attached the code in javascript

```js
<script>
            
            $(document).ready(function() {
                
               var tabla= $('#tablaEstudiantes').DataTable({
                       "destroy":true,
                       "processing":true,
                       "ajax":{
                           method:"POST",
                           url:"../ConsultaEstudiantes",
                           dataSrc:"datos"
                       },
                       columns:[
                           {data:"codigo"},
                            {data:"Nombres"},
                            {data:"Correo"},
                            {data:"Telefono"},
                            {data:"Estado"},
                            {data:"Campus"},
                            {data:"Facultad"},
                            {data:"Semestre"},
                            {data:"Modalidad"}
                       ]
                });
              
                //$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
            });
</script>
```

code used in servlet

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
 HttpServletResponse response)
             throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        
         Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
         PreparedStatement pst = null;
         ResultSet rs = null;
         
         try {
             String consulta = "SELECT estudiantes.Id_estudiante, estudiantes.Name_users, estudiantes.Mail_users,
 estudiantes.Phone_users, estudiantes.Estado_usuario,
 campus.Name_campus, faculta.Name, programa.Name_program,
 estudiantes.Semestre, estudiantes.Modalidad FROM estudiantes, campus,
 faculta, programa WHERE estudiantes.Id_campus = campus.Id_campus AND
 faculta.Id=estudiantes.Id_faculty AND
 programa.Id_program=estudiantes.Id_program;";
             pst =(PreparedStatement) conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(consulta);
             rs = pst.executeQuery(consulta);
             
             com.google.gson.JsonObject elementos =  new com.google.gson.JsonObject();
             com.google.gson.JsonArray array = new com.google.gson.JsonArray();
             
             while(rs.next()){
                com.google.gson.JsonObject item = new com.google.gson.JsonObject();
                 
                 item.addProperty("codigo", rs.getString("estudiantes.Id_estudiante"));
                 item.addProperty("nombre", rs.getString("estudiantes.Name_users"));
                 item.addProperty("correo", rs.getString("estudiantes.Mail_users"));
                 item.addProperty("telefono", rs.getString("estudiantes.Phone_users"));
                 item.addProperty("estado", rs.getString("estudiantes.Estado_usuario"));
                 item.addProperty("campus", rs.getString("campus.Name_campus"));
                 item.addProperty("facultad", rs.getString("faculta.Name"));
                 item.addProperty("programa", rs.getString("programa.Name_program"));
                 item.addProperty("semestre", rs.getString("estudiantes.Semestre"));
                 item.addProperty("modalidad", rs.getString("estudiantes.Modalidad"));                
                 
                 array.add(item);                
             }
             
             elementos.add("datos", array);
             
             out.print(elementos.toString());
             
         } catch (SQLException e) {
         }finally{
             try {
                 if(conexion != null) out.close();
                 if(pst != null) pst.close(); 
                 if(rs != null) rs.close();
             } catch (SQLException e) {
                 System.out.println("Error 4: " + e);
             }
         }
         
         
         
     }
```

I check but you are not sending me the ajax data or the type of error, I appreciate your collaboration is a small project that I am doing and I am new to the world of programming

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
item.addProperty("codigo", rs.getString("estudiantes.Id_estudiante"));
             item.addProperty("Nombre", rs.getString("estudiantes.Name_users"));
             item.addProperty("Correo", rs.getString("estudiantes.Mail_users"));
             item.addProperty("Telefono", rs.getString("estudiantes.Phone_users"));
             item.addProperty("Estado", rs.getString("estudiantes.Estado_usuario"));
             item.addProperty("Campus", rs.getString("campus.Name_campus"));
             item.addProperty("Facultad", rs.getString("faculta.Name"));
             item.addProperty("Programa", rs.getString("programa.Name_program"));
             item.addProperty("Semestre", rs.getString("estudiantes.Semestre"));
             item.addProperty("Modalidad", rs.getString("estudiantes.Modalidad"));
```

datatable must be case sensitive